# Cant see some pics on android but ok on emulator

Tags: javascript, react-native

I decided to look on my proj on android but some pics didnt display. Its wrapped in View. When i choose emulator, everythings fine. What problems can be? A path to pics is correct. Pics are png

I was trying to check imgs on another page of my project, but all the same